# append url with # using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to add hash url for example: #completed in the url using Ajax after form return success:

```
submitHandler:function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        target:'.result',              
        beforeSubmit:function(){ 
           $('.form-footer').addClass('progress');
        },
        error:function(){
           $('.form-footer').removeClass('progress');
        },
        success:function(){
            $('.form-footer').removeClass('progress');
            $('.alert-success').show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
            $('.field').removeClass("state-error, state-success");
            if( $('.alert-error').length == 0){
                $('#smart-form').resetForm();
                //reloadCaptcha();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What about using: `window.location.hash = '#completed'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add inside your `success` callback:

```
window.location.hash = '#completed';
```

and in `error` you could add similar

if however you wanted 1 saying that the url was called and dont care about success failure you could put into `finally` method instead